# regex.test() freezes webpage

Tags: javascript, regex, tags

I am writing a function that extracts the parameters in a URL, and I am using regex to identify if **an email** is present in the URL in order to remove it.

Here is my function :

```
function redactEmail() {
  var emailRedacted = ""; 
  try {
        var urlparams= window.location.search.replace("?","");
        var urlparamsdecoded = decodeURIComponent(urlparams);
        emailRedacted = urlparamsdecoded; 
        var emailRegex = /\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+/; 
        if (emailRegex.test(urlparamsdecoded)) {
                emailRedacted = urlparamsdecoded.replace(emailRegex, '[REDACTED EMAIL]');
        }
  }
  catch (e) {}      
  return emailRedacted;
}
```

This worked to return this :

`email=[REDACTED EMAIL]`

from this :

```
https://www.test.com/?email=test@test.com
```

But in some cases, this function is stopping the whole website from working.

*I am using this function in a tag on a website in GTM so I don't have access to the source code of the website.*

An example where the website stopped working is this :

```
https://www.test.com/?token=_JxY5kgHdKMkO8uSYf77sEl9mJhD7NHwAlrsMfJ-1zg
```

The website stopped working **completely**.

I debugged the function and the problem is with :

```
ow_emailRegex.test(ow_urlparamsdecoded)
```

1. Why is this error happening?
2. Is there an alternative to `test()`? `match()` did not work either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the dot or hyphen pattern inside groups *obligatory* to avoid having consequent `+`/`*`-quantifier patterns match the same chars:

```
\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*(?:\.\w{2,3})+
```

See how the regex fails gracefully against your string [here](https://regex101.com/r/op6a32/2).

Note that all `[\.-]?` are turned to `[.-]`, the whole `[.-]\w+` group is still optional as `*` matches 0 or more occurrences. The dot is not any special inside a character class, that's why I removed the backslash.

Also, you may use non-capturing groups since you are not interested in getting those submatches (and you actually can't in JavaScript).